# Text box content based on measures applied from a different page

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I have a text box where the content is derived from a measure looking at selected months in a slicer.

For example, I select start/end month in the slicer and the text box displays these concatenated with some text around them.

This works fine on the page with the slicer.

However, I would like to present the same data in a text box on a different page but when I copy the box over it's looking for data on the new page, can't find it and showing the exception message instead. Is there a way to reference the slicer/source on the original page?

This is the code:

```
SelectedValues_Label = VAR _Count = COUNTROWS(VALUES('Calendar'[Month Year]))
VAR _Concat = "Stuff is done between " & CONCATENATEX(VALUES('Calendar'[Month Year]),[Month Year]," - ")
RETURN IF(_Count>2,"Multiple Selection",_Concat)
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slicers do not share their selections across different pages by default.
You need to synchronize them across different pages.

[image]

[Enable sync slicers in PBI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/visuals/enable-sync-slicers)

If you need more flexibility or want to avoid having the same slicer visible on multiple pages, you can use bookmarks:

[Bookmarks in PBI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-bookmarks?tabs=powerbi-desktop)

Note that you are using a card visual and not a text box.